# MAC Address as Serial Number in Embedded Systems

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, mac

Is it ok to use a MAC Address as a serial number in an SoC with BLE? Are there any security threats to this perhaps? Or drawbacks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is ok, why wouldn't it be? Example is a cc2640 BLE chip from TI - here you can read the BLE MAC assigned by TI either by JTAG and Flash Programmer 2

[image]

or via the GAP protocol in software

```
GAPRole_GetParameter(GAPROLE_BD_ADDR, ownAddress);
```

What security risk would it present ?
This is the information I get when I look it up.

> Result for: 54-6C-0E-A0-4A-D5
>
> Address Prefix    54:6C:0E
>
> Vendor / Company  Texas Instruments
>
> Start Address 546C0E000000
>
> End Address   546C0EFFFFFF
>
> Company Address   12500 Ti Blvd Dallas Tx 75243 Us

Comment: Hi @sorenp, thank you for your answer. Just wanted to ensure that it is ok since I'm not sure if others have used it before as a serial no.

Comment: I use it as a unique identifier, which it is, and then I have a service that allows a user to enter their own identifier. But the MAC is my fail safe.

Comment: Good to know. I was concerned because online I read that the MAC can be changed through software and so I did not want to risk having duplicate MACs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on MAC Address (or more correctly, BDADDR) type. See [Core V.5.2](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=478726), 6.B.1.3.2. In BLE, there are two kinds of addresses:

- **Public**, that are IEEE-allocated as per [IEEE 802.3 MA-L (ex OUI) registry](https://standards.ieee.org/content/ieee-standards/en/products-services/regauth/oui/index.html),
- **Random**, that are not uniquely allocated at all. In turn, **Random** addresses may be:

  - **Resolvable**, they are short-lived and renewed periodically with some properties that make the address identifiable to whom knows something (IRK) about the device already (See 6.B.1.3.2.3),
  - **Unresolvable**, they are short-lived and renewed periodically, but with no guarantee whatsoever,
  - **Static**, they are constant for a given device, but with no uniqueness guarantee, just a (somewhat) low probability of collision, look for [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) to see how likely it is for a 46-bit address (because two bits are fixed).

So, if you want to use BDADDR as an identifier guaranteed to be unique, you can use it for sure when address is of the **Public** type, not in other cases. Depending on manufacturer, and SoC variant, you may get a **Public** address or a **Random** address. Some vendors make it a feature listed in the datasheet, others not. If this is not listed in the features, this may change in time. Check with your vendor for confirmation.